# Simplifying symbolic expressions involving dot products

Tags: simplifying-expressions, vector

I have a function that outputs a large expression containing dot products of vectors. None of the vector components are known, so all dot products are symbolic. For instance, part of the output may look like`2(p1.q1)(p3.p2) + (p1.p2)^2`.

I know what some of the dot products evaluate to. For example, I know things like:

```
p1.p1 = m
p1.p2 = 0
```

I want mathematica to simplify the expression as much as possible, making use of the known dot products and being sure to simplify all possible cancellation.

What is a good way to do this?

The way I am currently doing it is clunky and doesn't always work well. What I did was define a dot product function `d[x,y]` and then explicitly specified some of the dot products like `d[p1,p2] = m` and `d[p1,p2] = 0`. This became cumbersome because I constantly had to explicitly input commutitivity for each dot product (i.e. `d[p1,p2] = d[p2,p1] = 0`), and even when I did this, mathematica was not fully taking commutitivity into account when simplifying (via FullSimplify) my expression. Is there a better way?

Comment: To help you with your `d` function, you could `SetAttributes[d,Orderless]`.  Then all you need to define is `d[p1,p2]=m` (shouldn't the m be squared?).  Then `d[p1,p2]` and `d[p2,p1]` will automatically be replaced with `m`.

Comment: I also suggest that you investigate the option `TransformationFuntions` that is given to `Simplify` to teach it to handle expressions involving your `d` function.

Comment: The orderless attribute simplifies the code a lot, and Mathematica seems to have an easier time simplifying expressions after I added that.

Answer (score 5):

[`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand) knows about commutativity of vectors. So, one approach is to define [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) for your known relations (in canonical order):

```
p1 /: p1.p1 = m;
p2 /: p1.p2 = 0;
```

Then, use [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand) on your expression with the assumption that your variables are vectors:

```
TensorExpand[
    2 (p1.q1) (p3.p2) + (p1.p2)^2,
    Assumptions->(p1|p2|p3|q1) ∈ Vectors[d]
]
```

> 2 p1.q1 p2.p3

Answer (score 2):

You might formulate a list of rules that take into account the existing relations, such as the following. Assume there are 2 known relations `p1.p2=m`and `p1.q1=s`. The rules are as follows:

```
rules = {p1.p2 -> m, p2.p1 -> m, p1.q1 -> s, q1.p1 -> s};
```

Their application is straightforard:

```
    2 (p1.q1) (p3.p2) + (p1.p2)^2 /. rules

(*  m^2 + 2 s p3.p2   *)
```

Have fun!