# Inverse fuction of TensorExpand

Tags: simplifying-expressions, tensors

Is there a way in mathematica to factorize/simplify a dot product? I.e. I have something like a.b + a.c (obviously more complicated expressions) and I would like to factorize terms like

TensorSimplify[a.b+a.c] and return a.(b+c)

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`Dot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) performs several different operations depending on the shape of the arguments provided; it seems to me that these shapes need to be defined before simplification can be attempted.

Comment: Yes, of course a,b and c are defined as vectors...

Comment: Related: [(23423)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23423/121), [(66910)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66910/121).  Possible duplicate: [(126485)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126485/121)

Comment: Ok, defining up values are usefull, but it is not what I wanted. As I say, I would like to simplify dot expressions when all the objects are vectors. Let's say that p1+p2+..+pn = 0, and then I would like to simplify expressions of the type p_i.p_j+..- etc. Also, as far as I know there is no function that can factorize dot products, like the one that I wrote in the question.